# Ansible Openstack (import) include dictionary

Tags: ansible, openstack, ansible-inventory

I got one file that is creating a X number of VMs with different OS and Flavors.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    http_port: 80
    max_clients: 200
  tasks:
  - name: create VM
    os_server:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      state: present
      image: "{{ item.image }}"
      boot_from_volume: True
      security_groups: ssh
      flavor: "{{ item.flavor }}"
      key_name: mykey
      region_name: "{{ lookup('env', 'OS_REGION_NAME') }}"
      nics:
        - net-name: private
      wait: yes
    register: instances
    with_items:
      - { name: Debian Jessie, image: Debian Jessie 8 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: debian }
      - { name: Debian Stretch, image: Debian Stretch 9 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: debian }
      - { name: ubuntu Xenial, image: Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: ubuntu }
      - { name: ubuntu Trusty, image: Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: ubuntu }
      - { name: Fedora, image: Fedora 25 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: fedora }
      - { name: CentOS, image: CentOS 7 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: centos }
      - { name: Rstudio, image: RStudio Appliance  , flavor: c1.small, loginame: ubuntu }
      - { name: Spark Zepellin, image: Spark Zeppelin , flavor: m1.medium, loginame: ubuntu }
```

Now i want to split it into two files: main.yaml and vars.yaml. 
Main.yaml is creating the VM and vars.yaml is supposed to provide the arguments.
How can i do this? I tried to import it and i cant get it to work.

***************************main.yaml**********************************************

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    http_port: 80
    max_clients: 200
  tasks:
  - import_vars: vars.yaml
  - name: create VM
    os_server:
       name: "{{ item.name }}"
      state: present
      image: "{{ item.image }}"
      boot_from_volume: True
      security_groups: ssh
      flavor: "{{ item.flavor }}"
      key_name: mykey
      region_name: "{{ lookup('env', 'OS_REGION_NAME') }}"
      nics:
        - net-name: private
      wait: yes
    register: instances
```

***************************vars.yaml**********************************************

```
---
  with_items:
 - { name: Debian Jessie, image: Debian Jessie 8 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: debian }
 - { name: Debian Stretch, image: Debian Stretch 9 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: debian }
 - { name: ubuntu Xenial, image: Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: ubuntu }
 - { name: ubuntu Trusty, image: Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: ubuntu }
 - { name: Fedora, image: Fedora 25 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: fedora }
 - { name: CentOS, image: CentOS 7 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: centos }
 - { name: Rstudio, image: RStudio Appliance  , flavor: c1.small, loginame: ubuntu }
 - { name: Spark Zepellin, image: Spark Zeppelin , flavor: m1.medium, loginame: ubuntu }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud **not** use a wrongly indented `import_tasks` module to include variable files. Tasks are tasks, variables are variables ("vars").

Read the [Ansible docs: "Variable File Separation"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#variable-file-separation) before randomly typing something in.

One of the correct ways is:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    http_port: 80
    max_clients: 200
  vars_files:
    - vars.yaml
  tasks:
    # ...
```

---

And `with_items` is a directive for a task, so it should stay where it was.

You need to give a name to the variable containing the list and refer it in the `with_items` directive:

```
---
instance_definitions:
  - { name: Debian Jessie, image: Debian Jessie 8 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: debian }
  - { name: Debian Stretch, image: Debian Stretch 9 , flavor: c1.small, loginame: debian }
  # ...
```

and:

```
- name: create VM
  os_server:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    # ...
  register: instances
  with_items: "{{ instance_definitions }}"
```